# How to prove Separable Convolution layer is theoretically identical to traditional Convolution?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network

I have seen the saying that Separable Convolution layer is theoretically identical to traditional Convolution for so many times,
but yet no one has pointed out where the proof is.

God, I have google this for several hours,
but all those proofs I found are only in the case of 2D sobel filter which is spatial separable instead of depwise separable, and the situations would are totally different with 3D input in convolution layers (and actually the "convolutioin" here is actuall "cross-correlation......").

Is Separable Convolution layer is really identical to traditional Convolution mathmatically?
Where I can find the proof?
I would be very apperiated if you can point it out.

Comment: You need to understand matrix and tensor multiplication. Then the proof will become obvious.